How to change root without side effects
How can I, preferably without entering a new subshell, change root for the current shell, while keeping the same environment ? The assumption would be that the new root and sub-directories from that root are almost identical to the old root and its sub-directories. I'm working on a modern linux distribution, I'm okay with solution that wouldn't work on older OS'.
There is no concern in avoiding root escape, I do not intend to build a jail. I only hope to facilitate some process which will expect to find some file at some absolute path which won't be where it expect it to be.
If this is of any help, the new root is an overlayfs mount with its lowerdir pointing to /
Of course, I've looked into chroot, which seems to have a lot of unwanted side effects such as changing the current user (most likely because it is run with sudo) and changing the cwd.
I would appreciate any idea, might it be a shell command, script or C code.
Thank you kindly
